# Jenkins email-ext trigger e-mail for culprits not working as expected

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I'm trying to send e-mail to culprits when the build fails. If I start the build manually the e-mail is sent, but If I start the build through SCM polling e-mail is not send and the console output for the build shows the message:

```
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
```

Is that the right way the plugin should work (culprit should be a person, not scm polling)?

Im using:

OS: Ubuntu Server 11.04
Jekins: 1.532.1
Email-ext plugin: 2.37.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently (before the next release 2.38) when you want to send emails to the culprits you also need to check the "Developers" checkbox. Without it, the culprits portion will not be used at all.

This will be different going forward, adding Culprits as a recipient list will do what is expected.