# Jenkins Email-ext plugin not sending notification when new branch fails for first time

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

Steps to reproduce my problem:

1. Using GIT for SCM and Jenkins is set up to trigger build on SCM change
2. Master branch is building fine and all tests are passing
3. Create new branch from master
4. Break something so build fails and push to the new branch
5. Build is triggered in Jenkins by SCM change

Expected result is that email-ext plugin sends notification of build failure to the person who first pushed to the new branch.
But actually no e-mail is sent and the log says:

```
Email was triggered for: Failure - Any
Sending email for trigger: Failure - Any
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE
```

The "Failure - Any" trigger has both Developers and Culprits set under "Send To".
When a second commit is made to the new branch by the same person, the trigger works fine - it finds the e-mail address of the culprit and sends the e-mail.

Using Email-ext version 2.38.1, Jenkins 1.575.

The triggers I have configured:

[image: E-Mail triggers]

Screenshot from the first failing build after creating a new branch is below. (Branch is immediately broken)
I think the problem might be that it says "No changes", although it is triggered by a SCM change.

[image: Failing build in new branch]

If it is changed with a second commit, it will show that commit under "Changes" and then it knows who to send the e-mail to.

[image: Build after fixing commit]

Any way to get the plugin to send an e-mail to the one who creates the broken branch? Thank you.

Comment: What failure triggers have you configured for the email-ext plugin, and how? If possible click on the "Advanced" button, take a screenshot and add it to the description.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607197/jenkins-email-ext-trigger-e-mail-for-culprits-not-working-as-expected is similar to your question but your config and versions seem ok. Can you see Jenkins in the build's recent changes that Jenkins recognizes correctly the users?